# Express - res.send() works once

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new to Node and Express, I was trying to make something with Express just to get started, then I faced this problem.

First `res.send()` works well, but the second one doesn't fire.

Here's my code:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app     = express(),
    fs      = require('fs'),
    visits;


app.listen(8080);

app.get('/', function(req,res) {

    res.send('Hello');

    fs.readFile('counter.txt','utf-8', function(e,d) {

        if (e) { 
            console.log(e);
        }
        else {
            console.log(parseInt(d) + 1);
            fs.writeFile('counter.txt',parseInt(d) + 1);
            res.send('<p id="c">' + ( parseInt(d) + 1 ) + '</p>');
        }

    })
...
```

'Hello' is sent, but `res.send('<p> .. </p>');` isn't. If I comment `res.send('Hello');`, visitors will be shown.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`res.send()` is meant to be called just once.

Try this instead:

```
app.get('/', function(req,res) {
  var response = 'Hello';
  fs.readFile('counter.txt','utf-8', function(e,d) {
      if (e) {
        console.log(e);
        res.send(500, 'Something went wrong');
      }
      else {
        console.log(parseInt(d) + 1);
        fs.writeFile('counter.txt',parseInt(d) + 1);
        response += '<p id="c">' + ( parseInt(d) + 1 ) + '</p>';
        res.send(response);
      }
  })
});
```

(or just `res.send("Hello<p id=...")`, but you get the point :)

Comment: Thank you, I got it, so I have to call it just once and send everything I want, at once. ty!

Comment: Today I found the same issue and this post helped me a lot +1 to all :)

Answer (score 4):

This is because res.send() finishes sending the response.

When `res.send('Hello');` is encountered it sends the response immediately. So next `res.send` is not executed and you cannot see visitors. Commenting the first `res.send` allows you to view the second one.