# res.write takes long time to load

Tags: javascript, node.js

May I know why with below code. The browser takes a long time to load? I am new to express and node js. It takes almost 10s.If I was to replace res.write with console.log, the problem does not surface.

```
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.write("<!doctype html>");
    con.query('SELECT VoltageV from Voltage', function (err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err
    var output = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows));
            res.write("<SELECT>");
            res.write("</SELECT>");
    });
```

Comment: because the query is slow?

Comment: It cannot be the query because if I stick a console.log after the query, it gets printed immediately...yet the browser appears to be loading.

Comment: Do you end the request? `res.end()`

Comment: I get a "Error: write after end" if I end the request with res.end() .

Comment: The `.end` has to be after all `.write` methods

Comment: the .end is after all the .write .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15249808/express-res-send-works-once was helpful to my understanding. Using res.send suited me. Thanks. Problem has a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Node.js api document [Here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding_callback) it saids

> If this method is called and response.writeHead() has not been called, it will switch to implicit header mode and flush the implicit headers.
>
> This sends a chunk of the response body. This method may be called multiple times to provide successive parts of the body.

In short, your code is missing something that would affect performances, I think you will need to call `res.writeHead()` once and must be call before `res.end()`

But if this does not help at all, the answer from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422411/node-js-response-time) question here might answer your question about how res.write performance.